# Is there an integral equation to determine extrema?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

Typically, in order to find local extrema (min/max) of a function $f(x)$, one finds the zeros of the first derivative $f'(x)=0$ and then checks the sign of the lowest non-vanishing higher-order derivative iff it's even-order (if the lowest non-vanishing order is odd it is something like a saddle-point).

My question: Is there a (sensible) integral equation to describe this process without using differentiation?

Comment: Finding local extrema is a "local" job whereas doing integration is a "global" job.

Comment: @Vim True, but a first though would be using [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), at least for entire functions

Comment: Entire functions? I believe you were talking about real valued functions.

Comment: @Vim Both, though entire functions can be entirely real valued along $\mathbb R$ as well. And using some of those tricks to turn the $\oint$ into a $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ might work here, too...